# Mermaid in pdf Quarto

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, quarto, mermaid

I would like to use [`mermaid`](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/diagrams.html) diagrams in `Quarto` pdf. Here is some reproducible code:

````
---
title: "RenderTest"
format: pdf
---

```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
  A[Hard edge] --> B(Round edge)
  B --> C{Decision}
  C --> D[Result one]
  C --> E[Result two]
```
````

Output:

```
ERROR: No inspectable targets
```

So I get an error. On the Quarto page it says:

> For print output formats like pdf or docx, diagram rendering makes use
> use of the Chrome or Edge web browser to create a high-quality PNG.
> Quarto can automatically use an existing version of Chrome or Edge on
> your system, or alternatively if you don’t have either installed, can
> use a lighter-weight library version of Chrome (see Chrome Install
> below for details).

So I tried to install this using:

```
quarto tools install chromium
```

But I still get the error. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to use mermaid in Quarto pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/4883), after installing the latest version of Quarto (Version: 1.3.276), it is possible to use Mermaid in Quarto pdf. Here is the output now of the code above:

[image]

You could check which version is installed by using `quarto check` in your terminal. So make sure to install the latest version of Quarto, check this: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/releases/tag/v1.3.276

Comment: what command did you use. i used quarto render file.md and the mermaid diagrams are not rendering. quarto version is 1.3.450